# SQL - Combine search queries instead of multiple DB trips

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

A search term comes from UI to search entities of a table. The order that these search results should show up in UI is like this:

- First: exact match
- Second: starts with that term
- Third: contains a word of that term
- Forth: ends with that term
- Fifth: contains the term in any matter

So I first got the entities from DB:

```
result = entities.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(searchTerm)).ToList();
```

And then I rearranged them in memory:

```
var sortedEntities = result.Where(e => e.Name.ToLower() == searchTerm.ToLower())
    .Union(result.Where(e => e.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    .Union(result.Where(e => e.Name.Contains($" {searchTerm} ")))
    .Union(result.Where(e => e.Name.EndsWith(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    .Union(result.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(searchTerm)));
```

It was working fine until I added paging. Now if an exact match is on page 2 (in data coming from DB) it won't show up first.

The only solution I can think of is to separate the requests (so 5 requests in this case) and keep track of page size manually. My question is that is there a way to tell DB to respect that order and get the sorted data in one DB trip?

Comment: please provide code of your paging, that is not working now.

Comment: `entities.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(searchTerm)).Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
                .Take(pageSize).ToList();`

Comment: A main issue is that because of StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase you're using non-supported string methods, which makes EF-core auto-switch to client-side evaluation. It's likely that you don't need this comparison because the database collation is probably not case sensitive. Please first check that, because it matters for possible solutions to your problem.

Comment: @Gert Arnold - I moved the `Union`s to the request `IQueryable` and removed `StringComparison` and It seems that it's working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Then you can convert the `Unions` to `OrderByDescending/ThenByDescending` clauses to get the best matches on top.

Comment: Could you provide an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Can you modify your code of paging to last. which means after applying your where conditions. So that, first you doing filter and apply paging means to work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time to realize that you use `Union` in an attempt to order data by "match strength": first the ones that match exactly, then the ones that match with different case, etc. When I see `Union`s with predicates my Pavlov-conditioned mind translates it into `OR`s. I had to switch from [thinking fast to slow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinking,_Fast_and_Slow).

So the problem is that there is no predictable sorting. No doubt, the chained `Union` statements do produce a deterministic final sort order, but it's not necessarily the order of the `Union`s, because each `Union` also executes an implicit `Distinct`. The general rule is, if you want a specific sort order, use `OrderBy` methods.

Having said that, and taking...

```cs
var result = entities
    .Where(e => e.Name.Contains(searchTerm))
    .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

...the desired result *seems* to be obtainable by:

```cs
var sortedEntities = result
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.Name == searchTerm)
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.Name.ToLower() == searchTerm.ToLower())
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    ... etc.
```

(descending, because `false` orders `before` true)

However, if there are more matches than `pageSize` the ordering will be too late. If `pageSize = 20` and item 21 is the first exact match this item will not be on page 1. Which means: the ordering should be done *before* paging.

The first step would be to remove the `.ToList()` from the first statement. If you remove it, the first statement is an `IQueryable` expression and Entity Framework is able to combine the full statement into one SQL statement. The next step would be to move `Skip/Take` to the end of the full statement and it'll also be part of the SQL.

```cs
var result = entities.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(searchTerm));

var sortedEntities = result
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.Name == searchTerm)
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.Name.ToLower() == searchTerm.ToLower())
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    ... etc
    .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

But now a new problem blows in.

Since string comparison with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` isn't supported Entity Framework will auto-switch to [client-side evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) for part of the statement. All of the filtered results will be returned from the database, but most of the the ordering and all of the paging will be done in memory.

That may not be too bad when the filter is narrow, but very bad when it's wide. So, ultimately, to do this right, you have to remove `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` and settle with a somewhat less refined match strength. Bringing us to the

**End result**:

```cs
var result = entities.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(searchTerm));
var sortedEntities = result
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.Name == searchTerm)
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm))
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.Name.Contains($" {searchTerm} "))
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.Name.EndsWith(searchTerm))
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.Name.Contains(searchTerm))
    .Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Why "less refined"? Because, according your comments, the database collation isn't case sensitive, so SQL can't distinguish exact matches *by case* without adding `COLLATE` statements. That's something we can't do with LINQ.